# How to Inject all the children of an abstract class in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, inject

I have an AbstractService and extended by both child ServiceImpl1 and ServiceImpl2.

I need to inject all children at ones:

```
        constructor(
           @Inject('AbstractService') private children: AbstractService[]){}
        )
```

This is the error I got from my console browser:

```
 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyAbstractClassName]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyAbstractClassName]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for MyAbstractClassName!
        at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
        at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
        at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
        at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
        at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
        at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
```

Is it possible to do it and how? Or any idea?

Comment: You can't inject interfaces, they're not available at runtime

Comment: I know but thats not the problem, Im injecting an abstract class. Title updated

Comment: What exactly do you want to inject? could you show a simplified example of relations between your entities? It's not clear from the question

Comment: Thank you, updated